# Seeking a Code Analysis Tool for ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, code-analysis

I've inherited a rather complex AsP.Net 3.5 web application derived from
Several DLLs. I've used .Net Reflector to examine the DLL contents. However, I am looking for a code analysis tool that might help identify key class files, show how the application makes database calls (it's not obvious from the codebase), and generally suggests ways to improve the codebase.

Does such a (free?) tool exist?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at [NDepend](http://www.ndepend.com/) (no, it's not free). It might not do everything you want, but it's a great code analysis tool.

Answer (score 0):

I like AQTime from http://www.automatedqa.com/ for this.  There's a free trial.  The architecture tools in Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate also allow you to generate graphs from assemblies.

Edit:  You can also right-click on any method in VS 2010 and select Generate Sequence Diagram ... which is very helpful sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

how come you use reflector to examine the DLL's rather than visual studio?

There's a reflector plugin to decompile the DLL's back to projects: [FileDisassembler](http://www.denisbauer.com/NETTools/FileDisassembler.aspx)
Stepping thru the code in the VS debugger is the best code analysis tool, otherwise possibly even Rd-Gate Perf Profiler to record call stacks over time.

+1 for the architecture tools in Visual Studio 2010